# Changing android sdcard emulator permission

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, emulation, sd-card

I'm trying to use an sdcard iso file to my emulator. I've created the image file and include it to the emulator with -sdcard command. Now, every time I try to run my android application, it gives

```
[2012-10-19 17:14:59 - Emulator] qemu: could not open disk image D:\Data\Eclipse\sdcard_dev.iso: Operation not permitted"
```

Anybody know what to do?

Comment: use the `avd manager` to create the image, it should be `.img` and not `.iso`

Comment: I've tried it before but I don't know where the file is located so I created it with mksdcard

Comment: in win 7/vista, the .img is located at `c:\users\<username>\.android\<svd-name>\sdcard.img`

Comment: Now it says Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works after I did everything from scratch. Still dont know what cause it.